# Probability density function that integrates to 0

Tags: probability, integration

I'm running into a situation where I am calculating the definite integral for a probability density function as the first step in calculating probabilities with the CDF.

[PDF graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brErP.png)

$$\ f(x)= k |x| $$ 
$$\ -3 \le x \le 3 $$

$k$ has been evaluated as $1/9$ which you can tell from the graph

$$1/9\int_{-3}^3 x  = x^2/2 = 0$$

Now I understand that for f(x) to be a valid pdf then it must integrate to 1.

Where am I going wrong?

(Edited to reflect correct k value)

Comment: You should be integrating $|x|,$ not $x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$|x| = \begin{cases}
-x,& x < 0 \\
x,& x \geq 0
\end{cases}$$
If you don't see why this is, think of it this way: you have a negatively-sloped line for all negative numbers, and a positively-sloped line for all positive numbers. This can be seen from the graph.

Hence 
$$\int_{-3}^{3}|x|\text{ d}x = \int_{-3}^{0}-x\text{ d}x + \int_{0}^{3}x\text{ d}x$$
Note that intuitively, it doesn't make sense for $\int_{-3}^{3}|x|\text{ d}x$ to equal $0$ since $|x| \geq 0$ and is continuous, so that the only way that $\int_{-3}^{3}|x| \text{ d}x = 0$ would be if $|x| = 0$ in $(-3, 3)$ (which is obviously false).

For this particular problem, it would be easier to take the areas of the two triangles to find $\int_{-3}^{3}|x|\text{ d}x$ going from the line to the $x$-axis than to compute the integral directly. You have one triangle with vertices $(-3, 3)$, $(0, 0)$, and $(-3, 0)$ and another one with vertices $(3, 3)$, $(0, 0)$, and $(3, 0)$. Both have height $3$ and base $3$, so they both have areas $$\dfrac{1}{2}(3)(3) = 4.5\text{.}$$
You have two of these triangles, so the resulting integral is $4.5+4.5=9$.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Would it therefore hold that since $k=1/3$ that the triangles = $1/2(W)(H)$ = $1/2(3)(1/3) * 2 = 1$

Comment: @Praxis The height is $3$, not $1/3$, for each triangle. So, each triangle's area is $(1/2)(3)(3) = 9/2$ and the combined area is $9/2 * 2 = 9$. Hence, $$\int_{-3}^{3}|x| \text{ d}x = 9$$ and you have $9k = 1$. Thus, $k = 1/9$.

Comment: or $\int_{-3}^3\lvert x\rvert \operatorname d x = 2\int_0^3 x\operatorname d x = 2\cdot\tfrac{(3^2-0^2)}{2} = 9$ which is not that much more difficult to evaluate.

Comment: @Clarinetist can you tell me how you have determined the height of the triangles is 3? I know the answer is right but I just don't know how that is indicated. Incidentally, I need to prove this is the case without calculus initially.

Comment: @Praxis In the post, I gave the vertices of all three triangles. Since they are right triangles, all you need to do is notice that the height goes from $(-3, 0)$ to $(-3, 3)$ for the left-sided triangle, and $(3, 0)$ to $(3, 3)$ for the right sided triangle. See [here](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/qq/database/qq.09.05/kelsey1.html) for example.

Comment: @Clarinetist The verts of the LH triangle are (-3, 0) and (-3, k). The height isn't specified. How are we assuming the height is 3?

Comment: @Praxis This is calculating the integral of $|x|$, not $k|x|$.

Comment: @Praxis You could also use $k|x|$, but the base would be 3 and the height would be $3k$. Then your area would be $2*(1/2)(3)(3k) = 9k =1$, yielding the same answer.

Comment: @Clarinetist I see, the height is 3k, not k. That makes perfect sense. Many thanks!